How to clear the 'Browse for Location...' list in advanced search in Adobe Reader?
If you want to search in all pdfs located in a folder, you can open a pdf file,
then enter SHIFT+CTRL+F to enter avanced search mode.
In this advanced search mode, you can search through all pdfs in a folder. You can select 'all pdf documents in'. Then you get a drop-down, that also shows a list with the most recent searched folders. This list allows to easily select a search folder that you used before.
Problem: the folder paths in this list are abbreviated, and as a result, you are not really sure in what folder is going to be searched. For this reason, I just want clear that entire cached folder list.
How to clear this list?
I have been looking in Adobe settings for options to clear -> not found.
I have been looking in Adobe setting and files in folders below to find this list but nothing found.
C:\Users\this user\AppData\Roaming\Adobe
C:\Users\this user\AppData\Local\Adobe
C:\Users\this user\AppData\LocalLow\Adobe
